# NLog with Papertrail as target on Windows Azure Cloud Service (Worker Role)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, nlog

I am having hard time trying to send my logs to Papertrail (papertrailapp.com). According to their documentation this should be straigthforward.

Here is my NLog.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.Syslog" />
  </extensions>

  <variable name="VerboseLayout" value="${level:upperCase=true} | ${message} (${callsite:includeSourcePath=true})" />
  <variable name="ExceptionVerboseLayout" value="${VerboseLayout} ${newline} ${exception:format=ToString} ${newline} (${stacktrace:topFrames=10}) " />

  <targets>
    <!-- Papertrail -->
    <target name="papertrail" type="Syslog" syslogserver="logs.papertrailapp.com" port="PORT" facility="FACILITY" layout="${VerboseLayout}"/>
    <target name="papertrailException" type="FilteringWrapper" condition="length('${exception}')>0">
      <target type="Syslog" syslogserver="logs.papertrailapp.com" port="PORT" facility="FACILITY" layout="${ExceptionVerboseLayout}"/>
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" appendTo="papertrail, papertrailException" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I got the exact same config in my web application and it is working #1.

The NLog.config properties are correctly set (Copy always to output dir).

I tried to make it an embedded resource, I tried to set NLog config within the worker app.config using a custom  but did not work either.

I even added an inbound and outbound rules to allow papertrail port in the VM firewall.

All the assemblies are ok, NLog.dll, NLog.Targets.Syslog.dll

Anyone have been able to make it work?